# Изменение принципа закрытия модальных окон

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap

Здравствуйте!
Использую модальные окна bootstrap'а.

Я хочу, чтобы они закрывались не при клике на оверлей (Место не попадающее в модальное окно), а только при нажатии на крестик.

Если есть способ попроще решить данную проблему (писать своё окно не подходит), будет тоже очень здорово.

Comment: зачем лезть в код, если можно открыть справку?

Comment: @Grundy там есть ответ на данный вопрос?

Comment: Ну это же справка :-) сейчас добавлю ответ :-)

Comment: Правильно, кто читает инструкции? Кому они нужны?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, ой, да ладно вам нагнетать. Все учатся на своих ошибках :)

Comment: [RTFM](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-options)

Comment: @user234223 изначально почитав инструкции и документации

Comment: @Grundy так не честно :c

Comment: @user234223, что не честно?

Comment: @Grundy я тут сидел текст сочинял, а вы его отрезали.

Comment: @user234223, я оставил то, что важно для вопроса. Примерно таким вопрос и должен был быть с самого начала :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если обратиться к [справке](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-options) можно найти следующую опцию:

```
data-backdrop
```

`backdrop` — `boolean` или строка 'static' — по-умолчанию `true` — Добавляет backdrop элемент. Укажите `static` для backdrop, который не закрывает modal по клику.

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap-theme.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<a href="#" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#videoModal" data-backdrop="static">Popup</a>

<div class="modal fade" id="videoModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="videoModal" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-body">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
        <div>
          DATA
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Твой ответ не поможет, потому что основан на справке, а, значит, ТС не сможет его применить, ибо он не читает справки и мануалы :)